# Store data by session creation into session

Tags: session, jsf-2, listener

I need to store some data into the user session. Normally I would use `getSessionMap().put()` to solve this. My problem is, that I need to do this in the `sessionCreated()`-void of my sessionListener, but at this moment the FacesContext is still null. So the code below generates a NullPointerException.

```
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("data", "something");
    }
```

Is there another way to store data into the session or can I initialize an instance of FacesContext manually? Unfortunately I don't know much about the jsf lifecycle.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have completely missed the fact that JSF is merely one big abstract layer over the "plain" Servlet API and that `ExternalContext` (please take all time to carefully read its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html), including [method descriptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29)) merely delegates to classes/methods available in "plain" Servlet API.

In your particular case, when you use JSF on top of Servlet API (instead of Portlet API), then the `ExternalContext#getSessionMap()` is merely a facade of [`HttpSession#setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)/[`#getAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29). And guess what, `HttpSession` is in your `HttpSessionListener` readily available by the `HttpSessionEvent` argument!

```
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    event.getSession().setAttribute("data", "something");
}
```

This is then available by `getSessionMap().get("data")`, or by `@ManagedProperty("#{data}")` in any JSF backing bean, or just by `#{data}` in EL in a JSF page.